# Why does put() not work when used with indexed element in Query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an issue that `put()` does not appear to work if I access the model class as an indexed member of the `Query` directly; however, when I explicitly extract the class from the `Query` it seems to work fine. Why is this?

This code works:

```
class Record:
   field = db.StringProperty()

rs = Record.all().filter('name = ', name_str)
if rs.count() == 1:
   # assume that we only get one record in return...
   r = rs[0]
   r.field = some_value
   r.put()
```

and this code doesn't (and does not raise any errors)

```
class Record:
   field = db.StringProperty()

rs = Record.all().filter('name = ', name_str)
if rs.count() == 1:
   # assume that we only get one record in return...
   rs[0].field = some_value
   rs[0].put()
```

Comment: If you only want the first record, end your query with `.get()`. This will return the entity directly without the need for indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you index a query like this, it performs the query all over again, fetches the relevant result, decodes it, and returns it to you. In your second snippet, you modify one instance of the entity, immediately discard it, then fetch and store (unmodified) a second copy.

Generally, you should avoid indexing queries like this - call `.get()` or `.fetch()` instead.

For the same reason, you should avoid using `.count()` where possible, since it also requires running another query. If you only want one result, call `.get()`; if you need more, call `.fetch()` and then count the number of results returned.